# Two problems: one how to set a timer in the background, and the other is how to make a line refresh after a certain input

Tags: python, timer, refresh

i am making a board game, so far i've had no issues but i now both want to add a background timer for 5 mins to the overall game, and to allow the board to refresh on its own line as well as the input questions (so that there aren't 100 boards on the screen by the end) and a timer to too (if i don't forget)

this is the code for the questions

```
co1=input('who will be the first co-ordinate you will attack with?')
time.sleep(1)
co2=input('who will be the second co-ordinate you will attack with?')
time.sleep(1)
co3=input('who will be the third co-ordinate you will attack with?')
time.sleep(1)
co4=input('what is the first co-ordinate you will attack?')
time.sleep(1)
co5=input('what is the second co-ordinate you will attack?')
time.sleep(1)
co6=input('what is the third co-ordinate you will attack?')
```

(some long validation and movement code)
this is the boards code

```
print (' __________1_____________________2___________ ')
print ('=============================================')
print ('|', (1,1),  (2,1),  (3,1), '|', (4,1),  (5,1),  (6,1), '|')
print ('|', (1,2),  (2,2),  (3,2), '|', (4,2),  (5,2),  (6,2), '|')
print ('|', (1,3),  (2,3),  (3,3), '|', (4,3),  (5,3),  (6,3), '|')
print ('=============================================')
print ('|', (1,4),  (2,4),  (3,4), '|', (4,4),  (5,4),  (6,4), '|')
print ('|', (1,5),  (2,5),  (3,5), '|', (4,5),  (5,5),  (6,5), '|')
print ('|', (1,6),  (2,6),  (3,6), '|', (4,6),  (5,6),  (6,6), '|')
print ('=============================================')
print (' __________5_____________________4___________ ')
```

Comment: Please tag this with your programming language so the right people are able to assist you.
I'm guessing VB...

Comment: sorry i forgot about that, fixed